# How to prove that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ without using the definition of big oh?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computational-complexity

I have to indicate for $f(n)=\log n$ and $g(n)=\sqrt[k]{n}$ if $f(n)=O(g(n))$ and if $g(n)=O(f(n))$.

For $f(n)=O(g(n))$:

I found it hard to prove it using the definition of big oh so I decided to use the limit approach. I have to take the limit of the division and determine if the limit exists:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\sqrt[k]{n}}
$$

If the limit exists then $f(n)=O(g(n))$. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, though the existence of the limit is not *necessary*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So when I solve the limit what am I looking for?

Comment: The boundedness of the sequence $\frac{\log{n}}{\sqrt{k}{n}}$. Moreover the fact that it does not converge to zero.

Comment: @Lolman I know if it is bounded then the limit is not equal to $\pm\infty$ but how do I know if it doesn't converge to $0$?

Comment: Either you bound it from below or inspect the sequence $\frac{n^{1/k}}{\log{n}}$ and say that it is bounded.

Comment: @Lolman How would I do those things?

Comment: @user6607 use De l'Hopital.

Comment: Logarithmic function increases slower than *any* power function, so your limit is zero.